# Making flexible variable names

Tags: javascript, html

I have this variable which contains multiple values. I want the value to be unique. For example: 'q1'+ num : document.getElementById("q1").value

NOTE: num has a value of a unique number

```
var newItem = {

    'methv': document.getElementById("methv").value,
    'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value,

};
```

num on my php page has the value:

```
<input id="num" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post['unique person code']; ?>" />
```

i want this to be the unique identifier when adding to the variable. for example 'methv' + num : document.getElementById("methv").value

Comment: The question makes no sense in its current form. What does "want value to be flexible" mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: as in like a unique value which identifies this value because this function will be called multiple times

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample use cases. I still don't understand.

Comment: @user2162768: What function?  All you've shown us is an object.  What's not unique about your current object?  Can you please try to explain yourself more?  Show us an example of what you want, and what you are trying to do, and what's not working.

Comment: In your example, you're using `document.getElementById()` and you're using the element ID as the property name.  Since element IDs _should_ be unique, if you're using them correctly it logically follows that your property name would also be unique.  If your IDs are not unique, you should fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access objects like arrays, using `[]`.  So you can do:

```
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

var newItem = {};
newItem['methv'+num] = document.getElementById("methv").value;
```

Or, you can use `num` as its own key, then nest an object underneath that.  Like this:

```
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

var newItem = {};
newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
};
```

Comment: Thank You! sorry for the confusion earlier hard to explain the situation lol

Comment: It's ok.  After looking the question over a bit, I figured out what you wanted to do :)

Answer (score -1):

`eval(...)` is the answer:

```
eval( document.getElementById('methv').value + ": document.getElementById('methv').value");
```

eval allows you to generate sourcecode that uses values of your variables as variable names.

Comment: `eval` is ***NEVER*** the answer!  I'd suggest doing `newItem[document.getElementById('methv').value]` instead.

Comment: This code is very unsafe!  Also it's not even proper syntax.